# SPSS SQL selection

Tags: spss

I have a list with the targeted client IDs.I also have a huge database.I want to use SQL to selectively extract the information for only those IDs which are in my list.What is the SPSS syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Is a simple `LEFT INNER JOIN` not what's required here, with your left table being list of IDs?

Comment: I tried to follow this following example. However, I found that both t1 and t2 have to be in the same data base. But I have t1 in database, t2 is in local drive. Do you know how to designate the path for each table.? /SQL = "SELECT "
       "T1.[Employee ID] AS idnum, "
       "T2.[FullName] AS empname "
       "FROM Table1 as T1 INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2 "
       "ON T1.[Employee ID] = T2.[Employee ID] "
       "ORDER BY T2.[LastName], T2.[FirstName]"

Comment: You can edit your original post to include the syntax you've tried. As a comments it's not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you export your larger SPSS file into your SQL database, then @Jignesh Sutar is right, it's just a simple `left inner join.` If you save the file in SPSS as a .csv file, you can upload it into SQL pretty easily.